# Add item to every object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The "A" Model has columns like this when i get the with A->all() function

```
results:[{
       id: 1
       Name: "Johsnson",
       product_id: "Q-123",
  }, {
       id: 2
       Name: "Thomas",
       product_id: "Q-345",
  }
  // etc
```

and i got "Model" with structure like this

```
results: [{
       id:1
       product_id: "Q-123",
       product_name: "Apple",
  }, {
       id:2
       product_id: "Q-345",
       product_name: "Manggo",
  }
```

How can i return an object with all item in A model with addition of product_name with product_id key?

I tried

```php
$item= A::all();
foreach($item as $items){
  $name= B::select('product_name')->where('product_id',$items['product_id'])->get();
  $item->push($name);
}
```

but it doesn't work like i meant

expected result

```
results:[{
       id: 1
       Name: "Johsnson",
       product_id: "Q-123",
       product_name: "Apple", 
  }, {
       id: 2
       Name: "Thomas",
       product_id: "Q-345",
       product_name:"Manggo",
  }
```

Comment: preferred way to use `relationship` or solve it at `database` level instead of looping

Comment: Could you also post the code of the two models? It looks like you are missing a relation, or you missed the eager loading of the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like below

```
$item= A::all();
foreach($item as $key=>$items){
    $name= B::select('product_name')->where('product_id',$items['product_id'])->first();
    $item[$key] += array('product_name' => $name->product_name);
}
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. is it supposed to return $item ? anyway i add expected result on the post . thankyou in advance

Comment: just follow this line `$item[$key] += array('product_name' => $name->product_name);`. This line solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution:

```
$B = B::all();
$items = A::all()->map(function($item){
     $found = $B->where('product_id', $item->product_id)->first();
     $item->product_name = $found ? $found_produt
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) and [`Collection::map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map):

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```php
$item= Product::with('brand')->get()->map(function($product) {
    return (object)[
       'id' => $product->id,
       'Name' => $product->name,
       'product_id' => $product->product_id,
       'product_name' => $product->brand->product_name 
    ];
});
```